# Heatmap.2: add row/column labels on left/top without hard coding coordinates

Tags: r, bioinformatics, heatmap, dna-sequence

I'm trying to recreate a heatmap, using heatmap.2, similar to this[(1)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v517/n7535/full/nature13898.html):

[image: heatmap sample image]

I'm able to add the "A C G T" labels to the bottom column and right row labels. I'm trying to add "group" names to the top and left axis ("1012T3" etc. and "G>A" etc).

I've tried doing this through the `add.expr` function, but this overlays the text on top of the heatmap, and disappears when I try moving it to the left of the heatmap.

I've been able to add it by hard coding the coordinates like this[(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117753/r-how-to-build-angled-column-headings-above-columns-in-heatmap-2-pass-text-pl):

```
pos1 <- structure(list(x = c(0.222, 0.861), 
                   y = 0.993),
              .Names = c("x", "y"))

text(x=seq(pos1$x[1], pos1$x[2], len=6), y=rep(pos1$y[1],6)  ,
 srt=0, xpd=TRUE, adj = 0,
 labels=c('C>A', 'C>G', 'C>T', 'T>A', 'T>C', 'T>G') )
```

While it works, I'm not quite satisfied by somewhat hacky solution of having to hard code the coordinates. Does anyone have a solution to adding row/column labels to the left/top without hard coding the coordinates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A "ñapa" that I have found is by using the parameter, offsetRow.

i.e: heatmap.2(dataframe, offsetRow=-36). offsetRow with negative numbers move the labels to the left.